# PlaceHolder duplicating on button click-Insert Error too many arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having the user selecting the amount of textboxes as the need arises; however if the user selects 3 then on button click the count shows 6; hence inserting the data to the database table; it is saying that it has too many arguments. How can I stop it from duplicating and just pass the amount from the populate function.

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateNumber", connection, transaction))
                    {
                        int cont = ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
                        {
                            TextBox tx = (TextBox)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("tx" + i);
                            value = tx.Text;

                            int parsedValue;
                            if (!int.TryParse(value, out parsedValue))
                            {
                                lblError.Text = "Please enter only numeric values ";
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                   comm.Parameters["@loadSheetNum"].Value = lblSheet.Text; 
                                comm.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{if(!IsPostBack){    
    populate();
    }
    }

 public void populate()
{

    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCount.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tx" + i;


        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        tb.MaxLength = 10;
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Count is doubling up because you are adding literal control as well in content placeholder

Comment: yeah I remove and count is showing the correct amount  but it still saying that I have too much arguments

Comment: What is count variable value and how many parameters are defined in sp_CreateNumber

Comment: if I select 3 from the dropdownlist; the count is 3. two arguments

Comment: After command.executenonquery() try command.parameters.clear();

Comment: that helped but how do I get space between the textboxes

Comment: foreach(var ctl in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls) { if (typeof (ctl) is TextBox) { Textbox tx = (TextBox)ctl: //Rest of code goes here

Comment: So instead of looping on the contols count loop over the controls and if type of control is textbox proceed to execute stored proc

Comment: @MohsinMehmood; what if I want space between the textboxes, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Add spaces using the literal as u were doing earlier but use the loop over controls as I suggested in above comment

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, thanks alot, really appreciate it

Comment: @MohsinMehmood; is it possible to show how to read data from database into place holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is fixed by clearing out the SqlCommand parameters after each loop iteration.

```
comm.Parameters.Clear():
```